# Run SSIS package from SQL client

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I deployed my working package on server which is enterprise edition, SSIS installed on it. When I tries to run package by connecting to integration services engine from my desktop SQL client (which doesn't have SSIS installed) I get error "The task "Send Mail Task" cannot run on this edition of Integration Services. It requires a higher level edition."
Does it mean that I need to login to the server (RDP) and then run the package?

Also, when I schedule the package thru SQL agent it fails saying login time out but my windos auth login works for everything from connecting, deployment. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem - yes, you need to RDP into the server in order to use SSMS to start the package.  When you start it using SSMS on your client, it's attempting to launch the DTExec process on your client machine.  It's not running DTExec on the server.

Your second problem is likely a permissions issue.  Possibility #1: The connections you have set up on your package require your authentication information, and they don't have it because they're running as the Agent account.  You can fix that by creating a Proxy for your account and using that to run your job step.  Possibility #2: The connections you have set up on your package are having their sensitive information stripped out due to the default encryption on the packages that prevents anyone but "you" from seeing it - including a SQL Agent job that isn't running "as you".  The same resolution as above can help that (as well as others).

Comment: Do I need to RDP even for scheduling/executing job?

Comment: No, a scheduled job's execution location is by default the machine it is scheduled on.